# Remove tests that were not executed from Allure report

Tags: testng, test-report, allure

While running test I use different test-suites (xml files with list of tests to execute). E.g. I need to run smoke-tests so I choose corresponding xml with simplest tests (login/logout; selecting main tabs; check that data is displayed).

But in generated [allure](/questions/tagged/allure) report there are all test that are in the project (all methods with `@Test` annotation). And tests that have not been executed have statuses `passed`, `failed`; this information misleading to conclusion that we have tested more than we actually did.

**How can I fix this?** I need correct information about test execution (without misleading information that there are some more tests have been executed)

---

The same is inside [testng](/questions/tagged/testng) report; report states that all tests were executed, and some are even passed (but they actually have not even started).

---

**P.S.:** If it is not fixable, how do you deal with this (getting results for a subset of tests of your project)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After cleaning test results new report is generated without tests that are not included in test suite (xml).

Because I am using maven the command to clean results is:

```
mvn clean
```

Or:

[image]

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, could you please elaborate what was the problem and how did you solve it.

Comment: @NikunjAggarwal , I did not study background of the problem because solution was fast and simple: to clean allure report before test execution.